# postgresql multiple column search with ranking

Tags: postgresql, search, wildcard, pg

I want to search for multiple columns in multiple tables. Like this:
Given tables:

Users
id
first_name
last_name
email

Companies
user_id
address

Lands
name
company_id

Lets say User is Johny Bravo(johny.bravo@gmail.com) working in Washington in United States.
I want to find the record based on query
"ate" -> from United States, or
"rav" from Bravo

When I type "rav" my Johny Bravo rank is higher than Johny Bravos with other emails so it is first in results

How can I implement such functionality?
I've looked at ts_vector and ts_rank but it seems that it supports only right wildcard ("to_tsquery('Brav:*')") will work, also I don't need full-text-search functionalities(I will look for adresses and usernames so no need to alias names etc.) I can do wildcard search but then I would have to manually calculate ranking in application

Answer (score 2):

You could use [pg_trgm extension](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgtrgm.html).

You must have the contrib installed, then you install the extension:

```
create extension pg_trgm;
```

Then you can create trigram indexes:

```
create index user_idx on user using gist (user_data gist_trgm_ops);
```

And you can then query which will give you first 10 most similar values:

```
select * from user order by user_data <-> 'rav' limit 10;
```

Note that you can replace `user_data` with an immutable function, which can concatenate all of the info into one (text) field thus enabling search across more fields.

To get "ranking score", you can use [`similarity` function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgtrgm.html#PGTRGM-FUNC-TABLE), which returns 1 for identical strings and 0 for completely unrelated.

If you need full text search across whole database, a better solution might be a separate search facility, such as Apache Solr.

Comment: +1 to this answer, the only ting I would mention is to use `similarity()` function to give user the most relevant results.

Comment: Thanks for answer! Similarity func is not exactly what I want. I don't want to look for spelling mistakes but rank higher on multiple word occurrences. When ohny is in first name, email, and company name it's rank is higher. Any ideas what can I use for it?

Comment: @KubaAnonim this is 6 years later :D, but I have the exact same question, did you find a solution?